# React this is undefined

Tags: reactjs, this

React `this` is undefined in promise . Here is my code:

```
export default class Album extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    componentDidMount ()  {
        console.log(this.props.route.appState.tracks);  // `this` is working
        axios({
            method: 'get',
            url: '/api/album/' + this.props.params.id + '/' + 'tracks/',
            headers: {
                'Authorization': 'JWT ' + sessionStorage.getItem('token')
            }
        }).then(function (response) {
            console.log(response.data);
            this.props.route.appState.tracks.concat(response.data); // 'this' isn't working
        }).catch(function (response) {
            console.error(response);
            //sweetAlert("Oops!", response.data, "error");
        })
    }
```

here is the error code:

```
TypeError: this is undefined
Stack trace:
componentDidMount/<@webpack:///./static/apps/components/Album.jsx?:81:17
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Probably it's not binding `this`.

Try replacing with [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) if you're able to use ES6 syntax. It automatically binds this:

```
.then( (response) => {
        console.log(response.data);
        this.props.route.appState.tracks.concat(response.data); // 'this' isn't working
    } )
```

Or bind manually:

```
.then(function (response) {
            console.log(response.data);
            this.props.route.appState.tracks.concat(response.data);
        }.bind(this) )
```

Comment: Should we remove the `// 'this' isn't working` comment?

Answer (score 4):

You can bind `this` into thoes functions.
Or you also declare `self = this` in `componentDidMount` function. then using `self` instand of `this` in `axios`

**Other way**: using arrow function

Answer (score 2):

Example:

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      name: "My_Name"
    };
    this.componentDidMount = this.componentDidMount.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount () {
    let node = this.refs.term;
    term.focus();
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <div>
        <input type="text" ref="term" />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

or you can use this module [auto-bind](https://github.com/sindresorhus/auto-bind)