# When to use anonymous functions in JSX

Tags: reactjs, jsx

can someone explain the difference between

an anonymous function

```
  <button onClick={() => this.functionNameHere()}></button>
```

and

calling the function like below

```
  <button onClick={this.functionNameHere()}></button>
```

and also when to use either (such as different scenarios to use one over the other).

Answer (score 2):

The first example correctly binds the value of `this` (the exact problem lambdas strive to resolve in ES 2015).

```
 () => this.functionNameHere()
```

The latter uses the scoped-value of `this` which might not be what you expect it to be. For example:

```
export default class Album extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    componentDidMount ()  {
        console.log(this.props.route.appState.tracks);  // `this` is working
        axios({
            method: 'get',
            url: '/api/album/' + this.props.params.id + '/' + 'tracks/',
            headers: {
                'Authorization': 'JWT ' + sessionStorage.getItem('token')
            }
        }).then(function (response) {
            console.log(response.data);
            this.props.route.appState.tracks.concat(response.data); // 'this' isn't working
        }).catch(function (response) {
            console.error(response);
            //sweetAlert("Oops!", response.data, "error");
        })
    }
```

We would need to sub in a lambda here:

```
.then( (response) => {
        console.log(response.data);
        this.props.route.appState.tracks.concat(response.data); // 'this' isn't working
    } )
```

or bind manually:

```
.then(function (response) {
            console.log(response.data);
            this.props.route.appState.tracks.concat(response.data); // 'this' isn't working
        }.bind(this) )
```

Examples stolen from: [React this is undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38238512/react-this-is-undefined)

Answer (score 1):

In **ES6**, with the first scenario "this" refers to the Component where the function called belongs to. `<button onClick={() => this.functionNameHere()}></button>` is equivalent to `<button onClick={this.functionNameHere.bind(this)}></button>`.

On the other hand, in `<button onClick={this.functionNameHere()}></button>` "this" refers to the button itself.

I came from Python and I'm still a bit confuded about javascript context. Check this video for further info: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SBwoFkRjZvE&index=4&list=PLoYCgNOIyGABI011EYc-avPOsk1YsMUe_

Comment: if in the second example this refers to the button itself. How come when the page re-renders, the function gets called regardless? Shouldn't this.functionNameHere() be undefined then since the function was defined   as a class function not a button function?