# When should we use anonymous function in event listener in react?

Tags: reactjs

I am a React beginner. While learning React, sometimes I see people use anonymous functions in event listeners, I wonder if the below codes are the same. I think, to call function onDelete, we only need to use onClick={this.onDelete(id)}

```
    const cartItem=this.props.cart.map((bookCart)=>{
                return (    
    <Button onClick={()=>{this.onDelete(bookCart._id)}}>Delete</Button>
    )
},this;
```

and

```
    const cartItem=this.props.cart.map((bookCart)=>{
                return (    
    <Button onClick={this.onDelete(bookCart._id)}>Delete</Button>
    )
},this;
```

Comment: Dupe, check this, prob solves your doubts: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42322553/when-to-use-anonymous-functions-in-jsx

And also, regarding performance, this article is deff worth reading, will give you a lot of useful information if you're a React beginner: https://medium.com/@machnicki/handle-events-in-react-with-arrow-functions-ede88184bbb :)

Comment: Actually, your second example won't work since you're calling the function instead of just passing it. You have to use an arrow function or bind the arg.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use an arrow function when you need to pass arguments.

If you add parentheses to the function you are actually executing the function.

Therefore, with this code:

```
<Button onClick={ this.onDelete(bookCart._id) }>Delete</Button>
```

...you are setting **onClick** to the *result* of `this.onDelete(bookCart._id)`

If you use an arrow function like this:

```
<Button onClick={ () => this.onDelete(bookCart._id) }>Delete</Button>
```

...then you are setting **onClick** to a function that, when executed, will call `this.onDelete` with the parameters.

I hope this helps.