# React JS: Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined when updating from React.createClass

Tags: reactjs, components

I'm updating a React component to use:

**class SearchFilms extends React.Component**

instead of:

**var SearchFilms = React.createClass({**

When I do run this, I get the following error: **"Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined"**

Could anyone suggest how I could update this?

```
class SearchFilms extends React.Component { 
//var SearchFilms = React.createClass({

    getInitial() {
        return {
            userInput: ''
        };
    }

    onChange(event) {
        this.setState({
            userInput: event.target.value
        });
        this.props.newVal(event.target.value);
    }

    render() {
        var languages = ['Shutter Island', 'Inception', 'Titanic', 'Blood Diamond'];

        return (
            <div className="row" id="Nav">
                <input type="text" 
                    value={this.props.userInput}
                    onChange={this.onChange}
                />
            </div>
        )       
    }

}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32317154/uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-setstate-of-undefined)

Comment: you are switching from es5 to es6, in es6 you need to bind the function to use `this` keyword. to solve your issue put this line in the constructor: `this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this)` it will work :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

your `this` in `onChange` is `undefined`, which is caused by not binding.

add these:

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this);
}
```

FYI,

- https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/handling-events.html
- [React this is undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38238512/react-this-is-undefined)

Comment: This works great - thank you! I can see where I went wrong now